# Make array from js object php?

Tags: php

There is such a string parsed from html how to turn it into json ?

```
{key: 'ds:0', hash: '1', data:[[[11,[null,null,null,null,[null,null,"/store/games"]],"Игры"],[1,[null,null,null,null,[null,null,"/store/apps"]],"Приложения"],[9,[null,null,null,null,[null,null,"/store/movies"]],"Фильмы"],[5,[null,null,null,null,[null,null,"/store/books"]],"Книги"],[13,[null,null,null,null,[null,null,"/store/apps/category/FAMILY"]],"Детям"]]], sideChannel: {}}
```

I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work

```
$tipjson = preg_replace('/(\w+):\s+/', "\"$1\": ", $object);
$tipjson = preg_replace('/\'([^\']*)\'/', "\"$1\"", $tipjson);
```

Comment: That's not JSON. There's no reliable way to turn it into JSON without writing a complete parser. Regular expressions are not powerful enough.

Comment: @Barmar its site did this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: They've written a parser.